# Is there any way to upgrade brew cask

Tags: homebrew

Is there any way to upgrade all `brew cask`s? Something like `brew cask upgrade`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As of December, 2017, `brew cask upgrade` is a thing.

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/3396

Comment: `brew cask upgrade` is deprecated in favor of `brew upgrade --cask`.

Comment: `brew upgrade` without the `--formula` or `--cask` flag now updates both outdated casks _and_ formulae.

Answer (score 24):

### **Bash script to upgrade packages**

*inspired by [Pascal answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/215224/123008)*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(set -x; brew update;)

(set -x; brew cleanup;)
(set -x; brew cask cleanup;)

red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`

casks=( $(brew cask list) )

for cask in ${casks[@]}
do
    version=$(brew cask info $cask | sed -n "s/$cask:\ \(.*\)/\1/p")
    installed=$(find "/usr/local/Caskroom/$cask" -type d -maxdepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "$version")

    if [[ -z $installed ]]; then
        echo "${red}${cask}${reset} requires ${red}update${reset}."
        (set -x; brew cask uninstall $cask --force;)
        (set -x; brew cask install $cask --force;)
    else
        echo "${red}${cask}${reset} is ${green}up-to-date${reset}."
    fi
done
```

**What it does**

- update brew/brew cask, cleanup
- read the casks list
- check the `brew cask info` for the newest version
- install new version if available (and removes all old versions!)

**source:** https://gist.github.com/atais/9c72e469b1cbec35c7c430ce03de2a6b

**one liner for impatient:**

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/atais/9c72e469b1cbec35c7c430ce03de2a6b/raw/36808a0544628398f26b48f7a3c7b309872ca2c6/cask_upgrade.sh | bash /dev/stdin
```

**save as** `/usr/local/bin/cask-upgrade`, so you can run it locally as `cask-upgrade` later

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Would be nice to query for a list first of out of date packages first though.  Easy enough to tweak the script to do it.

Comment: Thank you! Have you tried to get this integrated directly into Homebrew Cask? I just converted it to fish and it works for me as well. It also revealed to me that some old versions were still present after I had installed the current ones.

Comment: You need to run `brew cask uninstall --force` before installing the new version if you do not want the old version to stay there.

Comment: @Pascal yeah I noticed I have a lot of old versions stacked here too. Soon I will add uninstall command.

Comment: @Atais does the deinstallation still consistently work for you? Some casks now leave an empty folder with the version number with my script, which messes with the version checking.

Comment: @Pascal to be honest I am now using homebrew-cask-upgrade :)

Comment: Warning: Calling `brew cask cleanup` is deprecated and will be disabled on 2018-09-30! Use `brew cleanup` instead.

Answer (score 23):

### **homebrew-cask-upgrade**

**I think this is by far the best solution to upgrade the casks.** 
*source:* https://github.com/buo/homebrew-cask-upgrade

**Installation & usage**

```
brew tap buo/cask-upgrade
brew update
brew cu
```

(Optional) Force upgrade outdated apps including the ones marked as latest:

```
brew cu --all
```

Comment: Very good solution. `brew cu -a` lists all installed casks and their version (current vs. latest) and allows for updating them individually or all at once. Also well designed and documented (`brew help cu`).

Comment: Copy from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968664/upgrade-all-the-casks-installed-via-homebrew-cask. Don't let the admin's catch you ; )

Comment: Same question same answer

Answer (score 11):

As the quote in the other answer says, there is currently no way to upgrade all updated casks.

The second part of the answer is wrong, though: `brew upgrade --all` cannot upgrade casks.

The only way to upgrade all casks is to get a list of the installed casks and force them to be reinstalled - including those that have not changed!

In [fish](http://fishshell.com), you could do that like this:

```
for app in (brew cask list)
    brew cask install --force $app
end
```

---

edit:

Atais created a script that works: [Bash script to upgrade packages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231020/151759).
Please upvote his answer rather than this one.

Comment: Well, mind that it will actually reinstall all your apps, not just update the outdated :(

Comment: To upgrade cask listings, you should run `brew cask update` then follow the earlier response to upgrade only the packages that are currently out of date here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231020/49601

Comment: @Danijel-JamesW I rolled your change back because it was wrong. It might be the way to do it in other shells, but it isn't in fish.

Answer (score 9):

From the [`homebrew cask` documentation](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md):

> Since the homebrew-cask repository is a Homebrew Tap, you'll pull down
>   the latest Casks every time you issue the regular Homebrew command
>   `brew update`. Currently, homebrew-cask cannot always detect if an
>   Application has been updated. You can force an update via the command
>   `brew cask install --force`. We are working on improving this.

The following should be enough to upgrade both brew formulaes and casks.

```
brew upgrade --all
```

Comment: This is not true anymore. `brew upgrade --all` is equivalent to `brew upgrade` now. Casks are not upgraded by that command.

Answer (score 6):

Casks with 'auto_updates' or 'version :latest' will not be upgraded; pass `--greedy` to upgrade them:

```
brew upgrade --cask --greedy
```

Comment: If you came here in 2022 it is the answer

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I have in my .bash_profile that I run to do a full upgrade pass of homebrew. I "pin" a couple items to keep gigantic downloads from being repeatedly fetched for every update, because their versions are always "latest" or they shouldn't be upgraded.

```
boop() {
  brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup \
    && cask-upgrade && cask-retire && brew cask cleanup \
      && brew doctor && brew cask doctor
}

__is_pinned() {
  local pinned=";pixate-studio;sketchup;skype;"
  [[ *";${1};"* != "${pinned}" ]] && return 0 || return 1
}

cask-upgrade() {
  while read -r; do
    reply=(${REPLY})
    name="${reply[0]}"
    vers="${reply[1]}"
    if ! __is_pinned "${name}"; then
      if [[ "${vers}" == "latest" ]]; then
        brew cask install "${name}" --force
      else
        brew cask install "${name}" 2> >(grep -v "re-install")
      fi
    fi
  done < <(brew cask list --versions)
}

cask-retire() {
  room="/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom"
  while read -r; do
    reply=(${REPLY})
    name="${reply[0]}"
    vers="${reply[1]}"
    if ! __is_pinned "${name}"; then
      for inst in $(ls "${room}/${name}"); do
        if [[ "${inst}" != "${vers}" ]]; then
          echo "Removing ${name} version ${inst}"
          rm -r "${room}/${name}/${inst}"
        fi
      done
    fi
  done < <(brew cask list --versions)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To reinstall brew cask apps in zsh:

```
brew cask update;

for app in $(brew cask list); do
    brew cask uninstall --force ${app}
    brew cask install --force ${app}    
done
```

Comment: This isn't very good for users who might have a lot of `brew cask` installations that require user input _(e.g. - quartz)_. Also, it's not necessary to uninstall every application before re-installing it. Ideally you should also run an update like `brew cask update` first.

Comment: @Danijel-JamesW Unfortunately it is if you do not want the old version to stay.

Answer (score 2):

This would probably be more appropriate as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to leave one, so...

As of this writing, `homebrew-cask` has its own upgrade system, and so the third-party scripts and tools are no longer required.

To list outdated casks: `brew cask outdated`

To upgrade all outdated casks: `brew cask upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

This has really irked me so I created this script to update all Brew apps and allow the user to choose which Cask apps to update. You can exclude apps from consideration too.

https://github.com/derrekyoung/ScriptsAndUtils/blob/master/brew-cask-upgrade.sh

Answer (score 1):

I recommend @eduncan911's answer in [the counterpart question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36339681/1404835).

In short:

- $ `brew-cask.sh` just lists an output similar to Homebrew's `brew update`.
  the list above shows all packages installed, with a green `✔` indicating any pending updates.
- $ `brew-cask.sh` upgrade will force the upgrade of those packages.

Install from his repo with:

```
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eduncan911/dotfiles/master/bin/brew-cask.sh --create-dirs -o ~/bin/brew-cask.sh
$ chmod 755 ~/bin/brew-cask.sh
```

Then use it like this:

```
$ brew-cask.sh
$ brew-cask.sh upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

I made such script by myself. Please look at the github https://github.com/pesh1983/brew_cask_upgrade. It has pretty good description, but if you have any additional question, feel free to ask me.
It does fair upgrade: uninstall and install, so any necessary cleanup will be performed by 'brew' itself.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @DarrenPMeyer, this would probably be more appropriate as a comment, but I too don't have enough reputation to leave one, so...

Adding on to @Raúl Cuza and @DarrenPMeyer's comments, some casks are considered auto-updating, but in my experience, many typically do not update promptly.

One can do `brew cask upgrade --greedy` or `brew cask outdated --greedy` to include those auto-updating casks.

---

Also, if you wanted to upgrade your casks automatically, I would suggest first installing homebrew-cask-upgrade:

```bsh
brew tap buo/cask-upgrade
brew update
brew cu
```

then scheduling `brew cu --all --cleanup --yes` in your crontab (we must use root's crontab because brew casks often need root permission):

```bsh
sudo crontab -e
```

and write:

```bsh
MAILTO=""
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
40 15 * * * brew cu --all --cleanup --yes
```

Comment: the `greedy` argument works well.

Answer (score 1):

since homebrew version 2.6.0 `brew cask upgrade` is deprecated and was replaced with `brew upgrade --cask`
(March 2021)

https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/

Answer (score 0):

```
for app in $(brew cask list); do
    cver="$(brew cask info "${app}" | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2)"
    ivers=$(ls -1 "/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/${app}/.metadata/" | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/ $//')
    aivers=(${ivers})
    nvers=$(echo ${#aivers[@]})
    echo "[*] Found ${app} in cask list. Latest available version is ${cver}. You have installed version(s): ${overs}"
    if [[ ${nvers} -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "${ivers}" | grep -q "^${cver}$" && { echo "[*] Latest version already installed :) Skipping changes ..."
        continue; }
    fi
    echo "[+] Fixing from ${ivers} to ${cver} ..."
    brew cask uninstall "${app}" --force
    brew cask install "${app}"
done
```

Comment: This is unreadable - also needs explanation of what it does